# How can you read only the number at the start of a line?

Tags: android, numbers

how can you read only the number at the start of a line?

Example:

> 1 something
>
> 2 and something
>
> 3 and something else

Read only the **number**, even when it is something like 542

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's always in the format `number words`, then you can:

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(lineString.replace(/\D+/, '')); // This uses a regex to remove all letters
```

OR

```
int number = lineString.split(" ")[0]; // Splits string by spaces and gets the first token, which will be numbers
```

where `lineString` is the string you want to parse, like `1 something`.

Answer (score 0):

int result = Integer.parseInt (mString.substring(0, 1));

Answer (score 0):

a trivial approach without regex:

```
private int readNum(String input){
    String buffer = "";
    char[] chars = input.toCharArray();
    for(char c: chars){
        if(Character.isDigit(c))
            buffer = buffer + c;
        else
            break;
    }
    return Integer.parseInt(buffer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method 'parse' of the NumberFormat class

`try {
    Log.i("TAG",((Number)NumberFormat.getInstance().parse("123efdsf4")).intValue()+"");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }`

This method will parse the String until it finds a char.